# Given a group in Crossfilter, get value by key

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

Given a group `g` in Crossfilter, what's the best way to get the value of a particular key `k`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I can come up with so far is:

`g.all().filter(function(item) { return item.key === k; })[0].value;`

It works, but seems a bit roundabout.

Comment: That's correct. It's worth noting that if you assign g.all().filter(function(item) { return item.key === k; })[0] to a variable, it's value property will continue to change as you apply filters to the Crossfilter.